# 2.4 at 20Mhz or 40Mhz increase range of network?

Tags: networking, wireless-router

Does either 20MHz or 40MHz increase the range of a network/ signal strength? Does it only increase the amount of packets it can handle?

Comment: @grawity - I was thinking the wrong kind of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

It’s strictly an increase in bandwidth. Unfortunately, the 2.4Ghz band is saturated and running with a 40Mhz bandwidth is likely to just make you more susceptible to interference and provide even worse performance.

There is no change in signal strength or distance.

Comment: I believe an increase in interference will affect the received signal strength indicator (RSSI) or the newer (RCPI). does it not affect the devices perceived signal distance?

Comment: https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/wireless-snr-rssi-and-noise-basics-of-wireless-troubleshooting/180314090744170/